# list append operator that doesn't do automatic unwrapping

Tags: kdb

Consider

```
q)-3!1,2
"1 2"
q)-3!1,enlist 2
"1 2"
q)-3!(enlist 1),enlist 2
"1 2"
q)-3!(enlist 1),2
"1 2"
```

This becomes quite annoying when dealing with lists as data structures representing sets and then sets of sets etc, so I have to define

```
q)app:{(enlist x) , enlist y}
q)-3!app[1;2]
"1 2"
q)-3!app[1;enlist 2]
"(1;,2)"
q)-3!app[enlist 1;enlist 2]
"(,1;,2)"
q)-3!app[enlist 1;2]
"(,1;2)"
```

which behaves "as expected" (from statically-typed pov that is).
The question is if there exists such operator builtin, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself. This operation is `enlist` of two (or more) arguments :

```
q)-3!enlist[1;2]
"1 2"
q)-3!enlist[1;enlist 2]
"(1;,2)"
q)-3!enlist[enlist 1;enlist 2]
"(,1;,2)"
q)-3!enlist[enlist 1;2]
"(,1;2)"
```